# run NodeJS REPL from inside a function

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I have a program that can be run in different mode depending on the request input command. One of the mode I am building is the NodeJS REPL server. So I did the following, were the run function is called when REPL mode is requested:

```
export function run() {
    // do some stuff
    repl.start({
        prompt: '> ',
        eval: (cmd, context, filename, callback) => {
            console.log(`receive: ${cmd}`);
            callback(null, JSON.parse(cmd));
        }
    });
}
```

The thing is that doing so, the REPL server launch properly but then immediatly ends. Whereas if I do the following in a standalone file, and launch it with `node standalonefile.js`, it works as expected.

```
    repl.start({
        prompt: '> ',
        eval: (cmd, context, filename, callback) => {
            console.log(`receive: ${cmd}`);
            callback(null, JSON.parse(cmd));
        }
    });
```

Comment: may the reason be that your code is just evaluated and executerd but nobody actually calls `run` exported function? Try to add in the first code snippet `run()` at the end of the file

Comment: the `run` function is actually called by the part of the code that is in charge of launching the right mode. It is actually called because if i add logs inside the run function and request that mode, they are printed.

Comment: Maybe it's not running with a terminal attached?

Comment: what do you mean ? the whole thing is launched from CLI doing `./MyProgram.exe <mode>`. the requested mode is thus launched from the currently opened terminal. I see the requested REPL mode launching, but it end right afer being completly opened.  May be this mode should be launched in a dedicated process/terminal ?

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved it using Promise. When the whole process ends it also ends the REPL process. Here, i wait for the resolving of the Promise before ending the whole thing.

```
export function run() {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        // do some stuff
        const server = repl.start({
            prompt: '> ',
            eval: (cmd, context, filename, callback) => {
                console.log(`receive: ${cmd}`);
                callback(null, JSON.parse(cmd));
            }
        });

        server.on('exit', () => {
            resolve();
        });
    });
}
```